# D3.js and JSP - data refresh is not happening

Tags: javascript, jsp, d3.js

I have created a treemap layout in d3js in a JSP file. I am connecting to a database and rendering data in to a JSON file and then displaying the data. Now i have 2 text boxes where i input my  'from' and 'to' date and click submit.  The connection to the database happens again and the same JSON file is reloaded with new data. But the treemap is not refreshed here. I am unable to figure out the issue here. Please help. Code below.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <style>
    div.bar {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 75px;   /* We'll override height later */
                margin-right: 2px;
                background-color: brown;
                }

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  <!-- margin: 50px 50px; -->
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height:550px;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.node {
  border: solid 1px white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 2px;
 }

 #tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        pointer-events: none;
}

#tooltip.hidden {
        display: none;
}

#tooltip p {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 20px;
}
.lables {
  border: solid 1px white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 5px;
 }

</style>

 <% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
%>

</head>
<body>
    <H4> A POC On D3.js with TreeMap Layout </H4>
        <form class="lables" action="Treemap_fetch.jsp">
                <label><input  type="radio" name="mode" value="size" checked> Clicks</label>    
        <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="ctr"> Ctr</label> 
        <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="searches"> Searches</label>                
                <br> <br>
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
                <label>to</label>
                <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <!-- onClick=fetch() -->
                <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </form>        
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
        <!-- <p><strong>Label</strong></p> -->
         <p><span id="value"></span></p> 
        </div>

        <%@page import="com.aol.poc.d3js.dbConnect.NetezzaJdbcConnection,com.aol.poc.d3js.properties.*" %>
        <%@page import="com.aol.poc.d3js.treemap.CsvToJson_V2,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.util.Date"%>

        <% 

        //String mode = request.getParameter("mode");
        String from="",to="";
        from = request.getParameter("from");
        to = request.getParameter("to");    

        NetezzaJdbcConnection njc = new NetezzaJdbcConnection();
        CsvToJson_V2 readCsv = new CsvToJson_V2();

        if(from == null || to == null){
            System.out.println("Inside if null");
            njc.extractData();
        }            
        else{
            System.out.println("Inside else");
            njc.extractData(from,to);
        }


            readCsv.readCsv(); 


       %>



<script>

 //var margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var width = 500; var height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .size([width, height])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { return d.clicks; });   

var svg = d3.select("body")         
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right )
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g");

    d3.json("data/OuputJSON.json", function(error,root){

    //alert("Inside json");
    var rects = svg.datum(root)
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(treemap.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
                        .call(position);

    var texts = svg.selectAll("text") 
                        .data(treemap.nodes)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text")
                        .call(textPrint);

    //Tooltip and highlighting starts
    d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover",mouseover); 
    d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseout",mouseout); 
    //Tooltip and Highlighting ends

    //Transition of the Treemap.
    d3.selectAll("input").on("change",change);                          

    function change(){

        var value = this.value;
        if (this.value === "ctr") { value =  function(d) {return d.ctr;}}
        else if (this.value === "searches") { value = function(d) {return d.searches;}}
        else { value = function(d) {return d.clicks;}}    
        //alert(value);
        rects
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()           
            .duration(1500)
            .call(position);    

        texts
            .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .delay(1500)
            .duration(500)
            .call(textPrint);
        }//change

}); //d3.json

function position(){

        this.attr("x", function(d) {return d.x;})
            .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y;})
            .attr("width", function(d) {return d.dx;})
            .attr("height", function(d) {return d.dy;})
            .attr("stroke","white")
            .attr("fill", function(d) {   //color(d.sub_group); });//return "teal" });
                        if(d.children == null)
                 return color(d.parent.sub_group); // color(d.parent.name);
            else
                 return null;                       
            });
}

function textPrint(){
    this.attr("x",function(d) {return d.x + 3;})
    .attr("y",function(d) {return d.y + 10;})
    .attr("class","node")                   
    .text(function(d){
            if(d.dx <= 10 || d.dy <= 10){ return ""; } //If the rect is too small do not display the text
                else if (d.children == null){
                    var pxK = 6.6,txtLngth = (d.clientid).length,txtAccomadate = Math.round(d.dx/pxK);
                    if (txtAccomadate >= txtLngth)                                      
                        return d.clientid;                              
                    else 
            return "";
                // return (d.clientid).substr(0,txtAccomadate);
        }
        else
                    return null;
        });
}

function mouseover(d){  

    // The below code is used for highlighting the element (i.e. rect) on mouse hover 
    d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill", "orange");

    //Get this rects x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (d.dx)/2;
    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + (d.dy)/2;

    //Update the tooltip position and value
    d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")
    .select("#value")
    .text(d.parent.sub_group+"--"+d.clientid);

    //Show the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);         

}

function mouseout(d) {    

    d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
    if(d.children == null)
        return color(d.parent.sub_group);
    else
        return null;                        
    })

    //Hide the tooltip
    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);  

}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: I have added the code. I understand that this problem might be because, the browser cache. But i have also added the code to clear the cache. It does not help again..

Comment: Did you verify that the data you are getting is indeed different?

Comment: Yes.I did that. The data is different. After the first time page loads, I will clear all the browser cache and then give the 'from' and 'to' date in the tect box. I do a submit and the treemap data is also changed. But if i dont clear the browser cache and just give the 'from' and 'to' date it doesnot. Please help

Comment: So the problem is not that the treemap isn't updating, but the browser cache?

Comment: Yes. Might be the browser cache. But how to resolve it. Each time I would not be able to request the end-user to delete the browser cache, before applying the dat filters. Any help is appreciated please

Comment: Add a query string to your URL. It won't do anything to the file, but prevent the browser from caching it, e.g. `data/OuputJSON.json?foo`.

Comment: It did not work this way. Can you tell me if I can add jsp file in the URL? and how can i return the JSON file from jsp file?

Comment: Yes, you can use a JSP file. I don't know how you would return JSON in your JSP.

Comment: yes, I am also not sure. Any other help possible? I am stuck in this from last 2 days and unable to get any solution.

Comment: After some efforts, I tried to generate the JSON file dynamically and feed the file name into d3.json function.(d3.json("<%= d3feed%>", function(error,root)). This part of the code works, but I have to put an alert statement. If i remove the alert it doesn't work. Any help on this, why this doesn't work when i remove the alert,